# Upgrade Grails Version in Netbeans and Add Shiro Security

Tags: grails, netbeans, netbeans6.8, grails-plugin, shiro

I have been working on the project where application is using grails 1.2.2....

Now I want to add the Shiro Security with the current project (using Netbeans), and I am very much new to the grails arena.

So, I wanted to know that how can add shiro plugin to my current project (in netbeans) ? May be I also need to upgrade my current project to version 1.3.3 or 1.3.4 I guess.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans doesn't really factor into it. Just run 'grails install-plugin shiro' from the commandline like you would for any plugin. You may need to adjust your classpath in Netbeans if you reference classes from the plugin, but a recent version of the IDE should handle that.